# vim navigation for very long lines

Tags: vim

I'm editing a text file with vim and I have wrap enabled using "set wrap". Suppose I have one very long line which has been wrapped to 10 lines. Lets say I'm on the 5th word(which is on the first line when wrapped) and I'd like to get to a word on the 7th line(when wrapped). Whats the fastest way I could get to that line. I'm not too keen on going `w<a-number>l` -- there is probably a better/easier way to do this, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- `gj` to go to line below (same line, but wrapped)
- `gk` to go to the above line.

I have a map in my .vimrc

```
map j gj
map k gk
```

Comment: didn't know that, thanks for the enlightenment

Answer (score 4):

There are several motions that specifically deal with `:set wrap`; mostly they are variants of the "normal" motions with `g` prefixed.

So there's `gj` and `gk` to move across *screen* lines, as well as `g0`, `g^`, `g$`, etc. Look them up with `:help` for more details.

Answer (score 1):

When you know the word or see it. for example it's *hello*, you might search for it with `/hello`. That should jump there. If there is a hello before, you can use `n` to get to the next one.

Answer (score 1):

As Paco says in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27687743/2445184), you can navigate screen lines with `gj` and `gk`. If that is too much hassle, as it probably is, you can add these lines to your `~/.vimrc` to have the normal arrow keys navigate in terms of screen lines instead of logical lines:

```
noremap  <silent> <Up>   gk
noremap  <silent> <Down> gj
noremap  <silent> <Home> g<Home>
noremap  <silent> <End>  g<End>
inoremap <silent> <Up>   <C-o>gk
inoremap <silent> <Down> <C-o>gj
inoremap <silent> <Home> <C-o>g<Home>
inoremap <silent> <End>  <C-o>g<End>
```

Comment: you do not want the <buffer> modifier in that case

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt This code works perfectly for me, so why should't I include the `<buffer>` modifier?

Comment: Because, when using the <buffer> the map is limited to only the buffer you cursor is currently in. It's a buffer-local mapping, while you seem to want a global mapping.

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt Since it's in the .vimrc, it takes effect for all buffers. Nevertheless, I've removed the `<buffer>` argument now, since it seems to be superfluous.

Comment: No, It only takes effect for the first buffer